# Standard wordpress importer seems to be missing blog images

Tags: import, bulk-import

I have 2000+ images and I've used the importer both locally and on my hosted site, the hosted site seems to have 100 less images though.

I'm importing from blogger.

I've ran the importer a few times and it still hasn't picked them up.

These images are supposed to get downloaded and stored locally from a blogger website but I'm short ~100.

Anyone else ran into this problem and know of a fix?

Comment: Perhaps the missing images are not attached to any posts? In which case WP would ignore them

Comment: @vancoder well there aren't any unattached images so I don't think so I don't think so.